# How to use a webservice method with key

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I'm trying to install and use a webservice in php.

I have the url : `http://cdt33.tourinsoft.com/soft/RechercheDynamique/Syndication/controle/syndication2.asmx`

And my code :

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://cdt33.tourinsoft.com/soft/RechercheDynamique/Syndication/controle/syndication2.asmx?wsdl");

$arFunctions = $client->__getFunctions();

foreach ($arFunctions as $function) {
    echo $function.'<br/>';
}
```

Here i can retrieve all methods of this webservice.

But i want to use this method : DataSet getListing(string $idModule), if i test with `idModule = dafda774-317d-4b5f-bb8b-33e5977dc13c` (my key) on the url, it works.

But I can not do it in PHP... any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

It's ok... I have find a way :

```
$rResultat = $client->getListing(
    array (
        'idModule' => "dafda774-317d-4b5f-bb8b-33e5977dc13c"));
```